# .NET VB or C# function to prevent software from being closed or killed unless reboot

Tags: .net

I want to program an anti distraction software like anti-social for windows since there is no windows version of it. [See the official web site](http://anti-social.cc/).

Anti-social can not be terminated while in block mode. User has to restart computer for that.

I have limited .NET experience. Any hints for frameworks to do that in .NET?

Thanks a lot.

(sorry my last post was too unspecific)

Comment: Pick a different tool - I wouldn't try to do this from a managed code application. To do the internet filtering, you're likely to need to work at a lower level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible (I don't think the linked app is unstoppable, too).

But you could try to create a system service checking if your application is running, and if it gets killed start it again. If you check in your application weather the system service is running and start it up again if someone shoots it up it could get difficult to stop it.

Comment: ... and make shure that application and service run under a different account than the user. If user has no admin rights it is harder to kill the app/service

Answer (score 0):

You can add a scheduled task at a small interval to check if your process is running and if not start it again.

Answer (score 0):

Create it as a service + front-end writing a hidden config.

Configure Recovery options for this service to reboot computer in case of stop, i.e.:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv1ZY.png]

Comment: Any user with stop access to the service can stop it.